# rewrite just the url in .htaccess and not change parameters passed to script with get

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite the URL part of a request but still pass the original request as a get parameter to php.

For example, my search url might be www.mysite.com/search/Search%20Request when the search request has been entered by the user and is multiple words, lower and upper case etc, I want to rewrite the url to all lowercase with no enocding signs etc, so the url is www.mysite.com/search/search-request but my get parameter gets passed correctly as &search=Search%20Request.

How can I rewrite just the url in .htaccess and not change the parameters I pass to my script with get.

Comment: You can't change the case with mod_rewrite directives, for example. That should be done in the scripts that gets the input for the search, I guess.

Comment: I can change all urls to lower case using RewriteMap  lc int:tolower and rules in .htaccess. I just don't want to also lower the parameter I pass to get.

Comment: [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) is not allowed in per-directory context (.htaccess files). You can use it in the server configuration files, though.

Comment: yes it's configured in .conf but the rules are in .htaccess.

Comment: Then, If I understand right, the rewrite rule to the GET script has to be first. For example `index.php?key1=$1...etc.`. Next the rule with the case conversion. Example: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (the_previous_one) [NC]` `RewriteRule .*  {lc:%1} [L]`

Comment: thanks @faa you are right, I didn't think about uaing two rules to achieve what I wanted.